# Asp.net 5 IHostingEnvironment exists in both

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In Startup constructor I'm getting parameter IHostingEnvironment and it can not resolve namespace:

> "The type IHostingEnvironment exists in both
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions and
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Interfaces"

I write:
Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment in ctor parameters, but I'm still getting this error. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Nuget settings:

[image]

Comment: I think you have messed up your references. Can you post the contents of your config.json file please?

Comment: config.json or project.json?

Comment: project.json...sorry

Comment: That looks ok. What is the address of the nuget feed you are using here?

Comment: I have 2 class libraries, which is included in this project, may be something wrong with class libraries?

Comment: Where can I find adress of nuget feed?

Comment: I have had similar messages when i have messed up the nuget feed. There are a couple of feeds; the stable and the bleeding edge (https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext). Check your nuget settings to see which one (or both!) are being used. I found I had to disable all the feeds except the one I wanted to use for this to be reliable..

Comment: Nuget feeds in VS2015 can be found under Tools>Options>Nuget Package Manager>Package Sources

Comment: I think this post outlines the issue you are facing https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/584

Comment: I added nuget settings screen, I didn't change anything yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both beta5 and beta4 packages together as your dependencies. They don't play nice together. Align all your dependency versions to beta5 ones. Run `dnu list` to see all resolved dependencies at the end.

More info: http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/